# Grouping data based on a condition (containing a specific string)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset similar to this:

Year | ID | Type
2000   1      O
2000   1      O
2000   1      O
2000   1      O
2000   1      R
2017   5      O
2017   5      O
2000   8      R
2000   8      O
2002   8      O

I want to create a code that groups the data by year and ID (I imagine it would use Dplyr) BUT it needs to have a condition: if in a given year there is any type R associated with an ID, then I want it to choose type R. If it has only O type, then the output must be O.

Example:
Year | ID | Type
2000   1      R
2017   5      O
2000   8      R
2002   8      O
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do an `arrange` on a logical vector (`TRUE` comes after `FALSE` in alphabetic order) and `slice` the first row after grouping

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   arrange(Year, ID, Type == 'O') %>%
   group_by(Year, ID) %>%
   slice_head(n = 1) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
   Year    ID Type 
  <int> <int> <chr>
1  2000     1 R    
2  2000     5 O    
3  2000     8 R    
4  2002     8 O
```

---

Or after the `arrange` use `distinct` which returns the first non-duplicated row

```
df1 %>%
    arrange(Year, ID, Type == 'O') %>%
    distinct(Year, ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

-output

```
 Year ID Type
1 2000  1    R
2 2000  5    O
3 2000  8    R
4 2002  8    O
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2002L), ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
8L, 8L, 8L), Type = c("O", "O", "O", "O", "R", "O", "O", "R", 
"O", "O")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can count the percentage of type R per year please? The example output table would be transformed into:
 Year    Percent
2000     0.66

2002      0

Comment: @PortoCrl can you add the expected in your post.  its is not clear from the comments

Comment: @PortoCrl do you need `df1 %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise(Percent = mean(Type == 'R'))`

Comment: Exactly. You're the best :) thanks